# Rails - Add extra columns to model or create additional association (table)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, optimization

I have two models on my app: `person` and `person_bio`

`person_bio` has 4 fields:

a person association(foreign key), a text column, a `source_id`(foreign_key) and a `bio_url`

A co-worker advised me to put all the new fields on `person` instead, since it will be less complex, and less heavy to insert/update

What would be the best choice, given that `person` has millions of records?

A bio would be optional, which means, we would have many NULL values, if the columns are inserted on `person` does that impact performance on mysql?

Comment: Though this is an opinion-based question, unless a Person has multiple PesonBios, it makes most sense to put it all on Person.  There's no functional need of a separate table for this data.

Comment: A person can have only one bio

Comment: What is your most use query? Pull all people or people log in and view/edit their bio?

Comment: looks more natural to have everything in one table as all the attributes (columns) seems to be part of the entity `person`.

Comment: Thanks guys, what do you consider when you create a new association, instead of putting more info into the model? Use it only for one-to-many associations?

Answer (score 4):

Though it depends on a lot of things, but in general, if the relation between `person` and `person_bio` is one to one, putting the fields of `person_bio` in `person` makes more sense since it reduces complexity.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends only on the way you are going to access to your data, i.e., if each time you retrieve the information for a person, you also need to retrieve the bio of such person, then put all the information together, if you only need the bio information in some situations, put them in separate tables.

That is taking into account the database performance.

Obviously, if you are creating some kind of API, you can have two different endpoints to retrieve the person information and the person information along with its bio.

Comment: Looking at your comments, if "A person can have only one bio" means that the person may not have any bio, it makes more suitable the separation into two tables approach. It is better having them separated, instead of having a lot of null attributes in your tuples.

Comment: yeah, a person may have one, but initially, we will have a bunch of null values. Geez.. now I am confused.